# Perl wget quotes syntax issue

Tags: perl, wget

thank you for reading.

For a shell command to wget, something like this works:

```
wget -q -O - http://www.myweb.com | grep -oe '\w*.\w*@\w*.\w*.\w\+' | sort -u
```

However, when I try to insert that command inside the Perl program, then I get a syntax error referring to "backslashes found where operator expected, bareword found where operator expected". So I replaced the quotes that surround the regex by this {} but, what that does is just like commenting it out, it does not bring the error, but it is as if the regex weren't, so obviously the curly braces are a wrong attempt.

This is the code, it is inside a foreach:

```
foreach(@my_array) {

$browser->get($_);
# and here below is where the error comes
system ('wget -q -O -"$_" | grep -oe '\w*.\w*@.\w*.\w\+' | sort -u');
```

If I replace the single quotes wrapping the regex by {}, then wget does get the URLs but the grep command does not act.

So that is the issue, how to resolve the quotes annoying the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
system ("wget -q -O -\"$_\" | grep -oe '\\w*.\\w*@.\\w*.\\w\\+' | sort -u");
```

You can include what you like within double quotes, only you have to escape certain characters.

Incidentally, Perl's `qq()` operator might interest you.  You can look it up.

Comment: Thank you to you two, thanks a lot, and now how can I grant in thanks the correct answer to the two of you ? I believe both are right, aren't they ?

Comment: You can upvote both but only *accept* one.  If it resolves the dilemma, you can just accept @simbabque's answer, since I presently have more reputation points than he, so that'll afford him a welcome boost.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: You could upvote both and select this answer because @thb answered first, or select the one that you like better. Happy to help.

Comment: @simbabque:  The gentleman insists, "You first!"  The other gentleman however won't have it: "No, sir, *you* first!"  Once one gets past the humorous aspect of this little farce, seriously, the world would be a rather better place if more followed your example.  (I bet that you spend one morning each year picking up litter on the side of the road.)

Comment: No, I don't. I do look for a bin when I have something to throw away, though. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are using single-quotes `'` in your system call. They do not fill in variables for you. The `$_` is not getting replaced. Also, the single quotes next to the `grep` make this invalid syntax.

Try this instead:

```
system ("wget -q -O - $_ | grep -oe '\w*.\w*\@.\w*.\w\+' | sort -u");
```

You can also use the [`qq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qq.html) operator:

```
system ( qq( wget -q -O - $_ | grep -oe '\w*.\w*\@.\w*.\w\+' | sort -u) );
```

Also, look at [perlop.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

---

Another thought: If you have `$browser` object that can `get()` the url, why do you need to use `wget`? You could also do this in Perl.

Comment: This is not a bad answer, but `wget -q -0 - "foo bar"` is not quite the same as `wget -q -0 - foo bar`.  Doesn't the OP want to retain the quotes?  Also, at least on my Perl interpreter, leaving the backslash unescaped doesn't seem to work, and would represent poor style in my view even if it did.

Comment: both answers are correct, both deserve the credit, how can I credit both of you ?

Comment: Thank you, thb. I just checked the backslashes. Since the OP doesn't use `\n` or the like, this works without escaping. I agree that it would be clearer were they escaped. I left it out as not to clutter. Regarding the singlequotes, in the command line example they were not there. I assumed that the OP put them in the perl code because he thought that would make it fill in the variable.

Comment: @thb . Well, wget does the recursive search throughout the website. Only, I dont want to download the website, I just want what the grep gets me. I dont know how to go recursively through the directories with Perl

Comment: @thb , or put it other way, all I need to do to have wget scan the web is -r, that is why I thought it would be easier than doing it with Perl, but although I am an enthusiast, I am still far from being an expert.

Comment: @iaintunderstand:  I think that you are right.  Certainly, one could program something recursive in Perl, with a suitable user-defined function and the use of Perl's builtins `readdir()` and `stat()`, but that's a lot of hassle if you have something with `wget` that does the job.  Nevertheless, if the `wget` doesn't seem neat enough to you (which I understand), then you could explore the `File::Find` module.  It might do what you want, the way you want.  Or, you can just stick with what you have.

Comment: Thank you very much, I truly appreciate your help and teachings. Best regards

Comment: I think he's not talking about files and folders but websites. In the case of following links, I agree that using `wget` is a lot quicker than using Perl. Laziness is great, keep it up!